# Can the decimal digits of $5^a + 7^b$ end in $82$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I had a question in my exam:

> Let a and b be a pair of positive integers.  In computing $5^a + 7^b$, one gets a number with two least significant decimal digits equal to $82$.  Is it possible?  Justify your answer.

How can I solve it?

My understanding of this question is that $5^a+7^b=82 \pmod {100}$ then I solve for $a = 1$ to $5$ and $b = 1$ to $5$ separately which gives me this pattern:

- $5^1=5 \pmod {100}$, $5^2=25 \pmod {100}$, $5^3= 25  \pmod {100}$ and so on.
- $7^0=1 \pmod {100}$, $7^1= 7 \pmod {100}$, $7^2=49 \pmod {100}$, $7^3=43 \pmod {100}$, $7^4=1 \pmod {100}$, $7^5=7 \pmod {100}$ and so on.

So the sum of its numbers can never be $82$; maximum it goes to $49+25$.  I just want to confirm am I right?  Or is there any other way to solve this?

Thanks

SJ

Comment: This is correct. However, in general, you cannot stop at exponent $5$ but only when the pattern goes in a cycle (which here is even before $5$ in the two cases).

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the proof is fine. Simpler: $\,{\rm mod}\ 20\!:\  5^{\large \Bbb N}\! + 7^{\large \Bbb N}\equiv\,\{5\} + \{1,7,9,3\} \not\ni\, 2$

Comment: how you get mod 20 and {1,7,9,3}?

Comment: Note $\ n\equiv 82\pmod{100}\,\Rightarrow\,100\mid n-82\,\Rightarrow\,20\mid n-82\,\Rightarrow\,n\equiv 82\equiv 2\pmod{20}.\,$ Now do the calculations mod $\,20\,$ that are analogous to your calculations mod $\,100,\,$ of all possible values of $\,5^a+7^b.\,$ Namely notice that mod $\,20\,$ we have $\,5^2\equiv 5,\,$ so $\,5^3\equiv 5(5^2)\equiv 5\cdot 5\equiv 5,\ldots, 5^k\equiv 5.\,$ and $\,7^2\equiv 9,\ 7^3\equiv 7(7^2)\equiv 7(9)\equiv 3,\ 7^4\equiv 7(7^3)\equiv 7(3)\equiv 1.\,$ But, mod $\,20,\,$ we cannot obtain $2$ by adding $5$ to the four possible values $\,\{1,7,9,3\}\,$ of $\,7^b.$

Answer (score 1):

This is a fine strategy, and probably the sort of thing you were supposed to think about for this exercise.

You can sometimes simplify your work a bit by choosing a smaller modulus dividing the one you actually want: e.g. any solutions modulo $100$ gives a solution modulo $4$... so if you can prove there are no solutions modulo $4$, then there can't be any solutions modulo $100$.

Or, at least, you can get some information about the solutions. Here, checking modulo $4$ would let you prove that if there were any solutions, then $b$ would have to be even.

In this particular case, however, I think it would just make things more complicated.

Comment: then for modulo 4, 82 become 2 ?Is there any other good way of doing this instead of checking the pattern of cycle?